# keeping track of items in store currently and that were instore at any given month

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a project and my client asked me for a feature that would alter the current db design I have. It is a custom logistics tool that would work only for them so cant use existing products (started with an open source one but i ended up changing a lot that i dumped it to start mine). Anyway...

They want to keep track of items in the store currently. But then say in 2020, they wanna say what items they had in store on January 2018. My model for items in store is as follows:

```
      id (auto-number)
      quantity
      instore (boolean to indicate if it is currently in store or not)
      arrivedin (date for when they item was put to the store)
```

When an item is given to employees, I would set instore to 0. When it is put back/returned, I would add another row of the item with a new arrivedin date and set instore=1

Now when a new month starts, I need to know how many items I had the previous month, add it with items that arrived in  the new month and say I had XYZ items in the new month. But then that looked like a chain query is going to be required.

If asked for February, I had to know how many arrived in February and how many I had in January then add them up. But then, I think I have to get the accurate total for January which would require me to check december of the previous years.

Am I overthinking this? Can anyone suggest a design that is suitable? I am on mysql.

Comment: I don't know why, but whenever I hit the word 'wanna', I stop reading.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of 'data warehouse' data store is called for here, so that you can keep the historical data (summarised sensibly) away from your live database (that's assuming that the historical data is only needed for reporting, not within the main application - not clear either way from the question).

Comment: hey MandyShaw...not sure if this will clear it up... quantity is always "1" for assets like laptop but for consumable items like juice and water, it is any positive decimal. But from what you are saying, I would need a separate table that would keep a total number of items that were instore at the end of each month, right? It would be historical table from my understanding and summarized. Am I getting you right? The above table is live one cos when items are needed for distribution, I am checking if they exist there or not. But let me give your idea a shot. Thanks for the hint.